# JSF/Prime (FileUpload component) multipart-form doesn't load managed-bean class param

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using NB 7.2.1 running on glassfifh 3.1 to develop a JSF/Primefaces 3.4 web app. So, when submiting the multipart-form enctype, the event fired by 'FileUploadListener' does not allow that another class attribute (like name or age in other JSF inputText) be loaded. Why?

Here is the view:

```
  <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p:outputLabel value="Nome" for="nome" />
    <p:inputText value="#{controller.nome}" id="nome" />
    <br />
    <p:fileUpload mode="advanced" multiple="true" fileUploadListener="#{controller.doSubmit}" />
  </h:form>
```

Here is the bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Controller {

  private String nome;

  public String getNome() {
    return nome;
  }
  public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
  }

  public Controller() {
  }

  public void doSubmit(FileUploadEvent event) {
    System.out.println(getNome());
  }
}
```

In previous 'getName()' call, null was returned. Therefore, everything is in the same form. Why I can retrive event.getFile() and dont retrieve getNome() ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "upload" button won't submit the whole form. It will only upload the file.
In order to submit the whole form, you need a normal submit button.

In the file upload listener method, you just have to get hold of the file as a variable in a view scoped bean, so that you can perform the necessary business logic on it in the action method associated with the normal submit button, along with all other input values.

E.g.

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p:outputLabel value="Nome" for="nome" />
    <p:inputText value="#{controller.nome}" id="nome" />
    <br />
    <p:fileUpload mode="advanced" multiple="true" fileUploadListener="#{controller.handleUpload}" />
    <p:commandButton value="submit" action="#{controller.doSubmit}" />
</h:form>
```

with

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Controller {

    private String nome;
    private List<File> files; // Whatever you need to get hold of all files.

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        files = new ArrayList<File>();
    }

    public void handleUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
        File file = save(event.getUploadedFile()); // Do your thing to save it.
        files.add(file);
    }

    public void doSubmit() {
        // Look, here you do the business job.
        System.out.println("Entered name: " + nome);
        System.out.println("Saved files: " + files);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so I'll have two sending operations: one for 'FileUpload' and another for the whole rest of the form?

Comment: Yes. Note that the file upload listener method is a **listener** method, not an action method (a listener method doesn't support navigation and swallows any thrown exception). Also note that when you use `<p:fileUpload mode="simple">`, then you obviously don't need the listener :)

Comment: Thanks again @BalusC, in the daily job environment some simple things looks like strange and dark answers!

Comment: @BalusC: In advanced mode with multiple file selected the user need to click upload button on the upload component, else **'fileuploadlistener'** will not be called.so is there a way to call the click event of upload button on form submit.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve a similar situation by using the process attribute of the PrimeFaces fileupload element. I listed all the components in my form that I wanted to "submit" after the file upload and without a separate button, there were only three. Note that this solution "submits" the component's values listed in process **after** the file is uploaded and in the order they are listed. Similarly I used the update attribute to update a component after the file upload was done. In this case add process="name" and it should do what you need it to.

```
  <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p:outputLabel value="Name" for="name" />
    <p:inputText value="#{controller.name}" id="name" />
    <br />
    <p:fileUpload process="name" mode="advanced" multiple="true" fileUploadListener="#{controller.handleUpload}" />
  </h:form>
```

Your managed bean will look something like:

```
    @ManagedBean
    @ViewScoped
    public class Controller {

        private String name;
        private List<File> files; // Whatever you need to get hold of all files.

        @PostConstruct
        public void init() {
            files = new ArrayList<File>();
        }

        public void handleUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
            File file = save(event.getUploadedFile()); // Do your thing to save it.
            files.add(file);
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;

            if(!files.isEmpty()) {
               // ... do something with name and files ...
            }
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve similar situation using **partialSubmit="true"** and **process**.
partialSubmit partially processed components to the ajax request post.

```
<h:outputLabel for="saType" value="Sa Type"/>
                <p:selectOneMenu id="saType" required="true" value="#{saUploadController.saDetails.listType}">
                    <p:ajax event="change" partialSubmit="true"/>
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="--select Type--"  itemValue=""/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{saUploadController.saTypes}"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <h:outputLabel value="*select a file :"/> 
                <p:fileUpload id="uploadedFile1" value="#{saUploadController.uploadedFile}" mode="advanced" fileUploadListener="#{saUploadController.handleFileUpload}" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(xml)$/" update="add:msgsAdd add:saType" process="saType"/>                      
                <p:message for="uploadedFile1" display="icon"/>
```

using `<p:ajax event="change" partialSubmit="true"/>`
we can partially submit the dropdown value and by `process="saType"` it will get dropdown item value for the handleFileUpload method